# Evaluating a developed system by application of a case study

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, systems-engineering, research

I am looking to the evaluation of a developed system to provide validity to my research. The system consists of manufacturing processes, procedures etc. and the plan is to implement the system at an industrial partner and manufacture certain products as cases for real-world evaluation.

Is this in fact a case study approach?

Myself as the researcher will obviously be involved in the implementation and operation of the systems, does this contradict the definition of a case study?

Are there other better-suited research methods for such an evaluation that I am missing? Possibly action research?

Are there research methods that can be applied prior to real-world implementation to assess such a system. In a type of hypothetical/prospective/illustrative manner?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context to help understand your intention?  Are you commercializing some private or academic research? Are you asking what the procedure / development process is that eventually leads up to "pilot production"?

Comment: Its for academic research. At this stage what I have developed is a conceptual framework, which needs to be evaluated in a real-world setting/within industry. I have look into apply a case study which I believed is a good option, although I often read conflicting statements when it comes to researcher involvement in conducting the case study and to what extent the researcher is a particpant and can be interventions